# Переменные могу интерпретироваться как const?

Tags: c++

Смотрел где хранятся локальные константы, и там был похожий пример, который изменял константу:

```
const int x = 1;
int* ptr = const_cast<int*>(&x);
*ptr = 45;
std::cout << *const_cast<int*>(&x);
```

И у меня возник вопрос, почему при прямом выводе `x`, значение остается `1`?
Из-за того что `x` интерпретируется как `const int`?

Comment: Ответ прост: изменение константной переменной вызывает _неопределённое поведение_. На практике компилятор может считать, что `x` никогда не изменится, и везде, где вы обращаетесь к значению переменной `x`, заменить это обращение на литерал `1`.

Comment: Это в целях любопытства

Comment: @wololo, `std::cout << *const_cast<int*>(&x)` почему при такой записи оно выведет 45, а при такой `*const_cast<const int*>(&x)` уже 1?

Comment: Это чтобы вам было интересней отлаживать программу, содержащую неопределённое поведение :) Как вариант, в первом случае разработчики компилятора решили честно читать из памяти модифицированную константу, а во втором решили заменить на литерал. Такое поведение не гарантируется. Например, gcc в обоих случаях [выводит `45`](https://godbolt.org/z/cs9T1P6e7).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Снять константность можно лишь в тех случаях, когда исходный объект не был константным.

```
int x = 1;
const int* cptr = &x;
int* ptr = const_cast<int*>(cptr);
*ptr = 45;
cout << *ptr << '\n' << *cptr << '\n' << x << '\n';
```

Тут все нормально, так как сам `x` не константный, но пришлось работать с указателем, посредством которого невозможно было изменить его значение. (**Ваш пример компилятор мог бы интерпретировать(изменить) таким образом, или вообще другим образом(это на его усмотрение), поэтому в результате будет неопределенное поведение**).

Или, скажем, другой пример(даже самый наивный чисто для демонстрации):

```
struct SomeType {
    
     SomeType(int y = 1) : x(y){}
     const int* getptr() { return &x; }
 private:
     int x;
 };
```

Тут геттер `SomeType::getptr` по хорошему должен быть  константным(const int* getptr() const ), чтобы для константных экземпляров вызвать член, который не меняет состояние объекта. В данном виде для объекта `const SomeType obj(3)` не сможем вызвать этот член, но мы точно знаем, что данная функция_член не пытается изменять его состояние, поэтому можем все же вызвать этот метод для него, сняв константность. Вот пример:

```
cout << *const_cast<SomeType*>(&obj)->getptr();
```

P.S.
Любой инструмент имеет свое предназначение, и  плохая привычка пытаться использовать его где попало...